# ‘Burdened with’ and ‘burdened by’

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I was wondering, what is the difference between ‘burdened someone with something’ and ‘burdened someone by something’?

Comment: Can you edit your question to give an example or two of each? I can think of examples of "burden someone with something" but none of "burden someone by something". There's "burden someone by **doing** something", but the difference there is already clear, and the version with "by" isn't common.

Comment: I *think* you can say e.g. "burdened by memories of war". Maybe it can be used for abstract matters?

Comment: Have you looked up 'by' and 'with' in a dictionary to see if there is any inherent difference? That would be the most basic of research for this question. If you are still unsure after that and can add that into your question, maybe we could help explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> I was hit *by* a thug, *with* a baseball bat.

In this example, the thing the person was hit 'with' was the item that actually made contact with them. The person they were hit 'by' was the cause of that.

In the case of a burden (literally something you are carrying, either physically, mentally or emotionally), you should consider what the thing is you actually have to deal with and how it came to be with you. Did someone else give the burden to you? If so, you may have been burdened *by someone*, but *with something*.